# Como remover linhas duplicadas de maneira eficiente?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou normalizando uma tabela aqui e descobri que há linhas duplicadas.

A forma que escolhi para limpar essas linhas é através do:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela_nova AS ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tabela_antiga
);
```

O problema dessa forma é que ela é muito lenta e dependendo do tamanho do banco, chega a demorar mais de um dia.

Haveria uma forma mais eficiente de eliminar as linhas duplicadas?

Comment: Não ficou claro o que esta duplicado na sua tabela, são codigos, nomes... da um exemplo(select) de como esta a sua tabela com os valores duplicados

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Foram dados importados. Há 20 colunas e 120 milhões de linhas. Umas 8 mil linhas estão duplicadas, isto é, possuem valores exatamente iguais para todas as colunas.

Comment: Você tem um backup desses dados?

Comment: Leia minha resposta abaixo, é só você compreender o que eu postei na resposta.

Comment: @IsraelSousa, vou ler sua resposta, não tive tempo ainda. Rapidinho

Comment: para ter mais eficiência e legibilidade no seu select nao coloque "distinct *" e sim o "distict campo", campo que deseja comparar

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Vamos assumir um exemplo com o banco de dados MySQL, com uma tabela chamada `nomes`, que contém os campos `id` e `nome`. Essa sintaxe pode ser usada em outros bancos, utilizaremos o seguinte comando:

```
DELETE a FROM nomes AS a, nomes AS b WHERE a.nome=b.nome AND a.id < b.id
```

Perceba que no comando SQL após o `FROM` eu chamo duas vezes a tabela `nomes`, mas as diferencio pelas letras `a` e `b`. Você poderia dar o nome que quisesse.

Note também que depois do `WHERE` eu faço a comparação entre as colunas, verificando a duplicidade e depois digo que o `id` de `a` deve ser menor que o de `b`. Dessa forma o MySQL vai comparar todos os registros com o mesmo `nome` e apagar aqueles que contenham o menor `id`.

- `nomes`: É a tabela com os registros duplicados.
- `nome`: É o campo para comparação dos registros.
- `id`: É a chave primária da tabela.

Veja na prática como acontece:

Tabela com os registros duplicados

| id | nome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | George |
| 2 | George |
| 3 | Caio |
| 4 | Caio |
| 5 | Érica |
| 6 | George Moura |
| 7 | George |
| 8 | Érica |
| 9 | George |
| 10 | Caio |
| 11 | George |
| 12 | João |

Aplicando o comando SQL descrito acima:

```
DELETE a FROM nomes AS a, nomes AS b WHERE a.nome=b.nome AND a.id < b.id
```

| id | nome |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | George Moura |
| 8 | Érica |
| 10 | Caio |
| 11 | George |
| 12 | João |

Caso queira apagar todos os registros duplicados, deixando apenas os registros únicos é só trocar o `<` por `!=`. Por exemplo, executando o SQL abaixo na tabela original, teríamos:

```
DELETE a FROM nomes AS a, nomes AS b WHERE a.nome=b.nome AND a.id != b.id
```

| id | nome |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | George Moura |
| 12 | João |

[Fonte](http://tableless.com.br/deletando-registros-duplicados-banco-de-dados/)

Comment: Por que essa maneira é mais eficiente que a do "SELECT DISTINCT"?

Comment: Eu acho mais simples de entender e compreender o que está acontecendo por debaixo dos panos. além de que também é muito bom para quando os **IDs** duplicados forem numéricos.

Comment: Mas ela é mais rápida?

Comment: Acredito que sim, pois você poderá especificar as columas que quer que sejam retornadas.

Comment: Vou te dar o certo, mas não sei bem se era a resposta que eu queria. Mas ok. Abs

Comment: Muito Bom.. Me ajudou. Só tem uma coisa, eu precisei alterar um pouco a minha query pra dar certo.. Veleu!

Answer (score -3):

DELETE a FROM tbl_xf AS a,tbl_xf AS b WHERE a.`fk_x`=b.`fk_x` AND a.`pk_x` < b.`pk_x` AND a.`fk_x`=8 AND b.`fk_x`=8