# Como excluir registros duplicados em uma tabela SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela onde preciso aplicar uma nova regar, a coluna A + B não podem ter o mesmo valor.

Pretendo adicionar uma regra assim:

```
ALTER TABLE minhatabela ADD CONSTRAINT minhaconstraintnome UNIQUE (coluna_A, coluna_B)
```

Mas para fazer isso eu preciso remover os registros que são "duplicados" desse valor.

A regra solicitada é que qualquer um dos dois ou mais registros fossem apagados, eu descobri que não existem mais de dois em cada caso assim:

```
SELECT coluna_A, coluna_B, count(*)
  FROM minhatabela
  group by coluna_A, coluna_B
  having count(*) > 1
```

Então, eu preciso excluir um dos dois registros duplicados, são mais de vinte mil casos, por isso queria fazer em um comando só, mas não sei como poderia se fazer isso.

Comment: Relacionado: [MySQL: Como remover linhas duplicadas de maneira eficiente?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68377/mysql-como-remover-linhas-duplicadas-de-maneira-eficiente)

Comment: Perfeito, vai funcionar, como eu marco isso como resposta?

Comment: Eu poderia marcar como duplicata, mas estou em dúvida porque a outra pergunta é especificamente sobre MySQL, e a sua é sobre SQL Server. Embora as respostas de lá funcionem perfeitamente no SQL Server...

Comment: A menos que um SGBD tenha um mecanismo proprietário pra fazer essa operação, eu não acho que faz sentido ter N perguntas com a mesma resposta (e mesmo que um SGBD tenha, acho que faz mais sentido detonar a tag `mysql` daquela pergunta e adicionar o mecanismo proprietário como uma resposta adicional **lá**).

Comment: @ctgPi Um mecanismo proprietário para isso eu não conheço, mas existem particularidades do TSQL que podem permitir fazer de outras maneiras no SQL Server (com um USING, por exemplo). Mas vou manter a decisão da comunidade aqui. Por enquanto não vou remover a tag mysql de lá (mas acrescentei sql), talvez isso valha uma discussão no meta. E obrigado pelas suas considerações, muito pertinentes.