# Deletar registro duplicado da tabela no PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, delete

#### Situação

Atualmente realizei um processo duas vezes na qual deveria ser processado apenas uma vez. Assim minha tabela foi populada duas vezes com os mesmos dados.

```
tb_kardex
cd_kardex | cd_item

tb_kardex
| 1 | 45875 |
| 2 | 45876 |
| 3 | 45877 |
| 4 | 45875 |
| 5 | 45876 |
| 6 | 45877 |
```

#### Duvida

Como deletar apenas o "segundo" registro do mesmo item?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como remover linhas duplicadas de maneira eficiente?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68377/como-remover-linhas-duplicadas-de-maneira-eficiente)

Comment: Então @Ricardo mysql != postgresql ... não tenho certeza se o que se aplica na outra resposta, pode ajudar nesta pergunta, votei por deixar aberta, mas talvez alguém que entenda de postgresql possa dizer a sua opinião :) - vou esperar

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu fiz o teste e não funcionou. Assim como na [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102903/sql-deletar-registro-duplicado-da-tabela?noredirect=1#comment210460_102906)

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, fiz uma alteração na minha resposta, o fiddle ele está com dados de exemplo apenas, mas excluir corretamente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faz assim:

```
DELETE a FROM nomes AS a, nomes AS b WHERE a.nome=b.nome AND a.id < b.id
```

Código [encontra aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68377/como-remover-linhas-duplicadas-de-maneira-eficiente)

**ATUALIZANDO**

Para postgreSQL 9.3 daria para fazer assim: ([Aqui um Fiddle funcionando](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/28e61/1))

```
DELETE FROM tb_kardex a
  where exists (select 1 from tb_kardex b 
      WHERE a.cd_kardex=b.cd_kardex 
        AND a.cd_item < b.cd_item);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solução

```
DELETE FROM tb_kardex
WHERE cd_kardex IN (
SELECT  cd_kardex
FROM
    (
        SELECT  cd_kardex,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY cd_item ORDER BY cd_kardex asc) AS rn -- CRIA UM CONTAGEM DE PARA CADA CD_ITEM REPETIDO
        FROM    tb_kardex                                       -- É IMPORTANTE A UTILIZAÇÃO DO ORDER PARA MANTER O RN 2
    ) A                                                         -- NO ULTIMO cd_kardex
WHERE   rn = 2
)
```

#### Alteração

Caso você tenha feito um processo se repetir varias vezes tendo mais de 2 rows altere o critério `rn > 1`.

Comment: Achei essa resposta também Guilherme. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025367/t-sql-deleting-all-duplicate-rows-but-keeping-one

Comment: Nossa isso que não tinha visto essa oO.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert ajudou? não arrisquei uma resposta porque é postgree.

Comment: @Marconi sim foi desse jeito que resolvi

Comment: Boa pergunta :).

Answer (score 1):

Conforme esta [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1746250/1518921)  você pode criar uma tabela temporária e usar `DISTINCT`:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp ...
INSERT INTO tmp SELECT DISTINCT * FROM t;
DROP TABLE t;
ALTER TABLE tmp RENAME TO t;
```

> Recomendo que faça um backup antes