# Apagar registros duplicados via php no mysql

Tags: mysql, query, mysqli

Bom dia pessoal, li alguns artigos aqui com problemas parecidos, mas nenhum me respondeu a minuncia, ao que eu quero. É o seguinte:

Eu tenho faço uma query para verificar quais linhas possuem um campo duplicado

```
SELECT IP, Count(*) FROM hardware GROUP BY IP HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

De posse da informação de quais ips estão duplicados, eu capturo o dado do campo IP em uma variável e deleto:

```
DELETE FROM hardware WHERE IP = '{$ip}'
```

Funciona bem, mas eu gostaria de apagar somente o registro mais antigo, mantendo o mais recente.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como remover linhas duplicadas de maneira eficiente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68377/como-remover-linhas-duplicadas-de-maneira-eficiente)

Comment: Crie uma trigger de insert para essa tabela, dessa forma quando um valor for inserido a trigger é disparada e você substitui o ip antigo pelo novo. Nunca fiz uma trigger com o Mysql, mas com o MSSQL é bem simples de se fazer.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como deletar todos os duplicados, exceto um?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166042/como-deletar-todos-os-duplicados-exceto-um)

Answer (score 1):

Execute a querie abaixo:
Ela cria sub consultas  filtrando primeiro as que possui  valor duplicado,
E depois adiciona o filtro removendo as de menor ID.

```
delete from hardware  where  hardware.id in 
(
  select * from  ( 
        select h1.id 
        from hardware h1 
        where h1.ip in ( SELECT h2.ip   FROM hardware h2   GROUP BY h2.IP  HAVING Count(h2.ip) > 1 )   
        and h1.id not in (SELECT min(h3.id) FROM hardware h3 GROUP BY h3.IP HAVING Count(h3.IP) > 1)  
   ) as subconsulta
)
```

Veja um exemplo aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/649a89/1

Answer (score 0):

*NOME_COLUNA é do tipo DATETIME*

**para excluir registros antes de 3 meses**

- DELETE FROM NOME_TABELA WHERE NOME_COLUNA < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);

**para excluir registros antes de 1 dia**

- DELETE FROM NOME_TABELA WHERE NOME_COLUNA < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);

***para excluir registros de uma data específica***

- DELETE FROM NOME_TABELA WHERE NOME_COLUNA < '2016-06-10 07:00:00';

// para excluir registros de uma data específica

- DELETE FROM NOME_TABELA WHERE DATE(NOME_COLUNA) < '2016-06-10';

Para saber quantas linhas serão excluídas, você pode usar o select abaixo:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NOME_TABELA 
WHERE NOME_COLUNA < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
Para saber qual a data de corte, use:

- SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);

Comment: não há nenhuma referência ao dado duplicado na sua query! Na sua query eu somente apagaria o campo.

Comment: Então nao entendi sua pergunta a  conforme citado: pagar somente o registro mais antigo, mantendo o mais recente

Answer (score 0):

a SQL abaixo deve servir pra você:

```
DELETE FROM hardware
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT a1.id
  FROM hardware a1
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      MAX(id) id,
      IP
    FROM `hardware`
    GROUP BY IP
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
  ) a2
  ON a2.IP = a1.IP AND a1.id != a2.id
)
```

**Explicação:**

1. A subquery a2 seleciona o ID mais recente dos registros de IP duplicados.
2. A subquery pai seleciona o id de todos os registros referentes ao IP da subquery a2, descartando os registros com IP mais recente.
3. A expressão DELETE remove os registros cujo id existem na lista dos registros duplicados mais antigos.

**Obs:** Se sua tabela não possui uma coluna para ID, você pode utilizar uma possível coluna de data de criação do registro, se houver. Caso não exista, você pode criar criar a coluna do ID, que irá receber os valores da ordem dos registros automaticamente pelo MySQL, com o seguinte comando:

```
ALTER TABLE hardware ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID' FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Comment: Jalber, testei sua query, mas me apareceu a seguinte mensagem "You can't specify target table 'hardware' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: Você pode dividir a SQL em duas operações. A primeira para pegar os ids e a segunda para a exclusão. Inclusive seu código ficará mais simples, o que facilita a manutenção.