# Excluir linhas repetidas

Tags: sql, sqlite

Bom dia,

Tenho uma tabela "Paciente" com as colunas (NO, Evento, Glicosimetro, Nome, Glicemia, Data, Leitura), qual melhor forma para excluir todas as linhas repetidas? Olhando na internet tentei o seguinte código porém não deu certo...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
   String sql = "DELETE a FROM Paciente AS a, Paciente AS b WHERE a.NO=b.NO AND a.Id < b.Id";
   SqlCeCommand comando = new SqlCeCommand(sql, con);
   comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
```

Comment: Seu código está como [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68378/100416). O que não deu certo? Dê um exemplo dos dados da tua tabela.

Comment: Reformulei a pergunta, desculpe.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como remover linhas duplicadas de maneira eficiente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68377/como-remover-linhas-duplicadas-de-maneira-eficiente)

Comment: Eu vi este post porém esta dando erro como mostrado na primeira imagem... Sabe me dizer o que poderia ser esse erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de executar esta rotina é quebrar a tarefa em duas.

Desta maneira, eu escreveria primeiro o `select` que resolve este problema. Creio que está pronto conforme o código que postou.

```
SELECT a.id, a.NO FROM Paciente AS a, Paciente AS b WHERE a.NO=b.NO AND a.Id < b.Id;
```

Após verificar se o `SELECT` inclui o conjunto de ids que deseja, você pode utilizar o comando `DELETE` para apagar as linhas duplicadas. (fazer backup antes).

```
DELETE FROM Paciente WHERE id IN (SELECT a.id FROM Paciente AS a, Paciente AS b WHERE a.NO=b.NO AND a.Id < b.Id);
```

Verifique que neste comando `DELETE` dentro da clausula `IN` estamos selecionando apenas os `ids`.